# Media controller not connecting after app is killed and relaunched

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-media3

I've been migrating to media3 (version 1.2.0) and I've been using [uamp](https://github.com/android/uamp/tree/media3) as guideline. There is a class [MusicServiceConnection](https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/media3/common/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/common/MusicServiceConnection.kt) that, as the name suggest, connects the UI with the media browser service equivalent.

In my app I'm providing/injecting a singleton instance using dagger2 of this class in the viewmodels where I need to observe/collect playback state.

Everything works well except, if I kill the app (swipe away from recents) while the audio is playing, then the next app launch MusicServiceConnection is not being recreated (I have a print log in it's init block that's not being called), thus the media browser is not connected and nothing (audio related) works.

I'm getting a warning log from Media Controller:

```
The controller is not connected. Ignoring setMediaItems()
The controller is not connected. Ignoring prepare()
```

Killing the app a second time and then relaunching it fixes the issue, but it's a bad UX.

Killing the app while audio has been paused doesn't cause the issue on the second app launch.
Not using a singleton also fixes it for some reason, however that causes other issues, so it's not a viable option.